# Can a static method call itself in Java?

Tags: java, methods, static

I have a static method, that deletes a ftp tree, so it needs to call itself recursively if it finds a sub dir, would it cause confusion because it's static ?

Edit : I didn't test before my post because if it causes a problem, I might have deleted extra files outside my test target, didn't want to risk it.

Comment: yes, a static method it can call itself recursively. What confusion could be caused? It seems you could have answered this yourself with a trivial experiment.

Comment: Wonder what stopped him from taking 10 seconds to find out, rather than 30 for an SO post that will end in flames.

Comment: i think he was just being 'Frank'

Comment: Sounds like you need version control. :/

Comment: -1 Why would you "test" on live and/or potentially dangerous code?

Comment: frank, you really need to change how you work if you can't test something as basic as this risk free.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it wouldn't, static methods can be used in recursive calls.

Answer (score 5):

nope.  you're good.  I apparently have to write at least 30 chars for this post to be accepted.

Comment: Upvoted for "I apparently have to write at least 30 chars for this post to be accepted."

Answer (score 2):

no. why would there be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

It'll only be a problem if your recursive method doesn't have a good stopping condition.  You'll find out quickly if that's the case - you'll get an OutOfMemoryError when the stack frames pile up on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't :) I do not see any reason for it to be more a problem than with an instance method.